# Vertices immediately clipping to 0,0,0

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges

I don't know what button my clumsy fingers hit, but when I'm in global mode and I tried to move an edge by manually typing the coordinates the control panel in edit mode, it doesn't move. And when I tried to do the same with a single vertex, it immediately went to X:0, Y:0, Z:0. But when I put it in Local mode and do the same thing, it behaves normally. What button did I hit and how do I fix it?[image: normal]

[image: about to change]

[image: clipping]

Comment: Is this an interaction /clipping/merging by the Mirror modifier? Try the same moves with the Mirror switched off?

Comment: Nope, I got rid of the mirror modifier and it still jumps to zero when I manually type it in.